# How to give src value in HTML5 audio tag using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4

i am creating an music website so i am trying to pass the name of the file when clicked on the musci cover image to the html5 audio tag.now I am playing songs using php but requiers to refresh the page before playing the audio but i want to do it with angularjs so the page won't refresh.

i am storing the file name as an Image Name so that i can won,t need to access my Database again to get the file name my code is

```
  <div class="container" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myController" ng- 
  init="select()">  

  <div  class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="file in files">  
 <a href="?play={{file.songname}}"><img ng-src="mainpagecontent/{{file.name}}" name="{{file.songname}}" ng-init="select()" onclick=""width="220" height="220" style="padding:16px; margin:2px;"  alt="music"/>  
  <br/>

 <label  style="margin-left:20px;padding-left:5px ">{{file.songname}}</label></a>


            </div>  
       </div>
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to play audio by clicking on an image?  Hard to be specific with out seeing more of your code but this should get you going with an example that you can adapt a bit to fit your need:

controller.js

```
$onInit(){
  this.sound1 = 'https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-21014/zapsplat_foley_brick_small_move_scrape_on_dirty_concrete_012_22190.mp3';
  this.sound2 = 'https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-18146/zapsplat_technology_vr_headset_phone_tray_holder_slide_out_then_in_19162.mp3';
  this.soundToPlay = this.sound1;
}

switchSound(){
  this.soundToPlay = (this.sound === this.sound1) ? this.sound2 : this.sound1;
}
```

index.html

```
<div>Audio url: {{$ctrl.soundToPlay}}</div>
<hr>
<button ng-click="$ctrl.playSound()">Play</button>
<audio
    id="test"
    controls
    src="{{$ctrl.soundToPlay}}">
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Hope this helps